# How to change weblogic data sources to point from current schema to new new schemas

Tags: java, weblogic, soa

I have a task to change SOA weblogic data-source to point from current schema to new schema, so after I point to new schema, DBA will drop the old schema.

How can I perform this by weblogic?

Do I need to go to: datasource -> select a datasource -> Connection pool -> Properties and
change User= xxx ?

Where is schema name define in datasource?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the "user" is the logon schema. Or in short: user == schema.